# Anonymous inner Class in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

In Java I can do the following:

```
interface SomeCallback {
  void onDone();
}
```

then I can create a function like this:

```
void test(SomeCallback callback) {
...
}
```

To call this function I do:

```
test(new SomeCallback() {
 @Override
 void done() {
 ...
 }
});
```

I want to do something similar in Swift. I could create a protocol

```
protocol SomeCallback : class {
  func done()
}
```

and a function like this

```
func test(callback: SomeCallback) {
...
}
```

I am still struggling with the call of this function.

Edit: Since I use an external API which requires a delegate I cannot use a Closure.

**Is it possible to create some kind of anonymous inner class like I did it in the Java example to call test()?**

Answer (score 2):

Update: If you can't use a closure/function, the direct answer is: **no, there are no anonymous inner classes**. However, [as Mike M points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29095457/573976), you'll have to use a class, and this class may be nested/inner to prevent polluting the global namespace. This class may well have a closure for every method it needs to implement and just call through to those closures.

---

The Swift-y way of doing this as long as you just need one method is to just use a lambda/closure.

For example, see [`NSComparator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparator), which is typealiased since it is used all over the place and you are meant to recognize it.

In your example, specifying a function type inline will do fine. So for example:

```
func test(callback: () -> Void) {
    ...
    callback()
}

// called as:
test({ in 
    ...
})

// or even (since it's the last parameter)
test { in 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Since I use an external API which requires a delegate I cannot use a Closure.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the syntax because what you wrote is a little confusing.

```
@objc protocol SomeCallback {
    func done() -> Void
}
```

No need to inherit from class as you wrote. Also, don't forget the @objc even if you do not want to bridge the protocol to that language. It helps with compiler complaints later on (might be a bug at the moment)

You cannot instantiate a protocol in Swift. You can however have an internal class that inherits from NSObject (root object) and implements this.

```
class External: NSObject {

    class Internal : SomeCallback {
        func done() {
            // does something
        }
    }
    let int = Internal()

    func test(callback : SomeCallback) {
        // additional work
        callback.done()
    }
}
```